# Why doesn't the following code make a new value for the variable?

Tags: java

```
class Cube{
    int side;
    int area = side * side;
}

public class Chronos{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Cube a = new Cube();
        a.side = 2;
        System.out.println(a.area);
    }
}
```

My question is why does it output "0" instead of multiplying the given variable 
`a.side=2` by itself and giving `a.area=4`.
My thought process was that it would see the command to print `a.area`, check back with `Cube` and see it's supposed to multiply `a.side`, which had been determined earlier, by itself.

Comment: Read about constructors.

Comment: When you update `side`, the value for `area` is not updated automatically. You would have to use e.g. `class Cube { int side; public int getArea() { return side * side; }}`

Comment: *"which had been determined earlier, by itself."* - yes, at that point `side` was 0, therefore area is `0` as well, the value does not simply recompute itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because

```
int area=side*side
```

happens when you initialize a cube object, so it is set to, as 0*0 = 0;

To change this you have to make a method i.e. setSide or getArea, and do the calculation there. i.e. (no need to use the area variable at all)

```
public int getArea(){
   return side*side;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cube a=new Cube();
```

When you do that, The variables are initialised with default values. And later you are just setting the variable `size`. That doesn't mean that the whole class magiacally refreshes.

While initialising both variables initialized with default values (0). Hence you seeing 0's.

You need to set area too. Or ideally, write a method to give area. And there you can `return size*size`

```
class Cube{
    int side;
    public int getArea(){
      return side * side;
    }
}
```

And then in main

```
public class Chronos{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Cube a = new Cube();
        a.side = 2;
        System.out.println(a.getArea());
    }
}
```

This is how you get latest values.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `Cube` instance, first the instance variables are initialized and then the constructor body is executed.

```
int side;
```

is assigned a default value of 0

```
int area=side*side;
```

is assigned 0, since 0*0 is 0

Only later, after the `Cube` instance is initialized, your `a.side=2` statement sets `a.side` to 2, but that doesn't affect the already computed `a.area`, which is not re-calculated.

If you allow the `side` property to be modified after the instance is created, you must modify `area` whenever `side` is updated. Or you can eliminate the `area` property and calculate it on demand.

That's what setters and getters are for:

Either modify `area` when `side` is modified:

```
public void setSide (int side) {
    this.side = side;
    this.area = side * side;
}
```

or remove the `area` property, and instead use:

```
public int computeArea () {
    return side * side;
}
```

Your corresponding `main` would be:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Cube a = new Cube();
    a.setSide(2);
    System.out.println(a.getArea()); // if setSide also modifies the area property
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Cube a = new Cube();
    a.setSide(2);
    System.out.println(a.computeArea()); // if you remove the area property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a object it will take default values. You are assigning a value to variable that won't refresh. So better to maintain setters and getters and then perform your operations accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a problem with the fundamental understanding of how classes are initialized.

The `area = side * side` statement is executed when the class is instantiated, or in other words when you do `Cube a = new Cube();`.

After that, `area` is never modified again. This is why you should *never* initialize class member variables to a non-constant value, as you could easily lose track of what it is.

You should make a new method to compute the area, such as:

```
class Cube{
    int side;

    public int getArea(){
        return side * side;
    }
}
```